# Ubuntu issue with upgrade

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I got the below error while upgrading the Ubuntu version from 20.04 to 22.04. I have tried to create an Ubuntu info file but It didn't help me. Kindly help resolve the issue

[image: error]

```
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lw9k2sm2/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lw9k2sm2/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lw9k2sm2/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2042, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lw9k2sm2/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1873, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lw9k2sm2/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 906, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lw9k2sm2/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 99, in run
    func()   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lw9k2sm2/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 122, in jammyPostInitialUpdate
    self._test_and_fail_on_pam_tally()   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-lw9k2sm2/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 394, in _test_and_fail_on_pam_tally
    with open(os.path.join('/etc/pam.d', f)) as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman.dpkg-backup'
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Dec 11 14:45:48 2023) ===
```

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman.dpkg-backup'` suggests that this may be a remote system controlled via RDP, and that a backup file is missing.

Comment: @ user535733 Ok How to resolve the FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman.dpkg-backup' ?

Comment: The reference to `self._test_and_fail_on_pam_tally()` make me wonder if the issue is related to this: [Upgrade from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 fails - unmet dependencies: libpam-modules](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1977493). Does your system use `pam_tally` or `pam_tally2` currently?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to check that, but I tried to get the version.                        
 apt list --installed | grep libpam-modules.

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libpam-modules-bin/focal-updates,focal-security,now 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.6 amd64 [installed]
libpam-modules/focal-updates,focal-security,now 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.6 amd64 [installed]

Comment: If anyone came across this error before kindly help me to resolve it.

Comment: Just before, I removed the xrdp backup file from the server using the following command: rm -Rf /etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman.dpkg-backup. Then, I ran the do-release-upgrade command again, and now I didn’t get the error as before. I hope I can reinstall the xrdp package using the following command sudo apt-get install --reinstall xrdp after upgrading the server, if I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the xrdp backup file from the server using the following command: rm -Rf /etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman.dpkg-backup. Then, I ran the do-release-upgrade command again, and now I didn’t get the error as before. I hope I can reinstall the xrdp package using the following command sudo apt-get install --reinstall xrdp after upgrading the server, if I want to